# First command always executing with switch discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, switch-statement

I'm having trouble with a switch statement using JavaScript and discord.js. I want the bot to execute both commands with and without the prefix. When I try to execute a command without the prefix it works, but then when I try to execute a prefix command the bot responds with both the command I asked it, and the first case in my non-prefix commands. Here's the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')
const token = "xxx"

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
})

client.commands = new Discord.Collection()

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

for (const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)

    client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

//ready event

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('online')
})

const prefix = 'ao'

//message event

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    var command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if(message.author.bot) return;

    //non-prefix commands

    switch(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
        
        case message.content.includes('ping'):
            message.reply('pong')

            break;

        case message.content.includes('hello'):
            message.reply('hello')

            break;
    }

    //prefix commands

    switch(command){

        case command = 'ciao':
            message.reply('ciao')

            break;
    }

})

client.login(token)
```

So for example, if I type only "hello", or "ping", the bot replies with the correct commands, but when I try to use "prefix + ciao", the bot responds with either "pong" and "ciao".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that what you are trying to do in your code is not at all how `switch` statements work. Let's first look at how `switch` statements actually are supposed to work.

**How `switch` Statements Work**

Let's say you have a value like `message.content` that you want to check the value of repeatedly. For example, you want to know if `message.content == "ping"`, you want to know if `message.content == "hello"`, etc. One way of writing this would be like so, with classic `if` statements:

```js
if (message.content == "ping") {
    // Do stuff for ping
}
else if (message.content == "hello") {
    // Do stuff for hello
}

//... and so on

else {
    // Do stuff if none of the above cases equals value of message.content
}
```

As you can see, this gets very long and repetitive if you have dozens of values you want to compare with the same `message.content` variable. `switch` statements are a shortcut that works exactly like the `if` statements above, but with more concise and less repetitive syntax. Here is what the above `if` statements would look like rewritten as a `switch` statement:

```js
switch (message.content) {
    case "ping":
        // Do stuff for ping
        break;

    case "hello":
        // Do stuff for hello
        break;

    //... and so on

    default:
        // Do stuff if none of the above cases equals value of message.content
        break;
}
```

As you can see, the `switch` statement is a lot cleaner and less repetitive, making it preferred in situations like discord bot command-handling.

**The Problem**

Now that we've looked at how `switch` statements are supposed to work, let's see how you've actually been using them. First, your non-prefix one:

```js
switch(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
        
        case message.content.includes('ping'):
            message.reply('pong')

            break;

        case message.content.includes('hello'):
            message.reply('hello')

            break;
    }
```

Now, let's look at this code using the test case that isn't working properly for you: when the message content is `prefix + "ciao"`. Since the prefix is present in this message, `!message.content.startsWith(prefix)` evaluates to `false`. Now, let's convert all other values in the above `switch` statement to what they would evaluate to:

```js
switch(false){
        
        case false: //message doesn't include 'ping'
            message.reply('pong')

            break;

        case false: //message doesn't include 'hello'
            message.reply('hello')

            break;
    }
```

Do you see why you are having your problem now? Your first `switch` statement is basically the equivalent of doing a bunch of `if (false == false)` statements, so whenever you do `prefix + "ciao"`, the first `case` in the first `switch` will always be executed.

That is the problem with your first `switch`, but your second also has issues:

```js
switch(command){

        case command = 'ciao':
            message.reply('ciao')

            break;
    }
```

What is happening in the `case` is technically invalid syntax. `command = 'ciao'` sets the value of the variable `command` to `'ciao'`, it does not truly check for the case that `command` is equal to `'ciao'`. However, assignment statements like `x = y` do return `y`, which is why this second `switch` ended up working for you. However, we can make that simpler by removing the unnecessary `x =`.

**The Solution**

To fix these problems, you will need to do two things. First, fix the syntax and logical issues in your `switch` statements. Second, reorder and reorganize your code to properly separate the logic for prefix and non-prefix commands.

Here are the fixes I have made. I have added comments explaining some of the changes:

```js
var args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/); //Args with no prefix
var command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); //Command with no prefix

if(message.author.bot) return;

//non-prefix commands

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) { //Check if no prefix with 'if'

    switch(command){
        
        case 'ping': //Use proper 'switch' and 'case' syntax like so
            message.reply('pong')

            break;

        case 'hello':
            message.reply('hello')

            break;
    }

}

//prefix commands

else {

    //Args and command accounting for prefix
    args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    switch(command){

        case 'ciao': //Removed incorrect "command = 'ciao'" syntax
            message.reply('ciao')

            break;
    }

}
```

This should solve the issue you are having and fix the issues with your `switch` statement. And, since the actual `switch` syntax is much simpler than the one you were attempting to use, it should be much easier for you to add commands as well.

Comment: thank you man! I understand now. Thanks for your help <3